# Unable to run Node Script file from Laravel Controller function

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, process, google-translate-api

I am trying to run node js file function from Laravel Controller function. Basically Node js file called as `translate.js` have function which can `translate input text to required language` ( Like english to hindi etc..)

I have done some testing with debugging but each time I got an Error while execute Node script from Laravel Controller function.

**Error I got :**

> The command ""node D:\Laragon\www\krutech\translate.js ""I want to try
> convert my text into hindi language."" hi"" failed. Exit Code:
> 1(General error) Working directory: D:\Laragon\www\krutech\public
> Output: ================ Error Output: ================ The filename,
> directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

**Where `D:\Laragon\www\krutech\translate.js` is node js file inside root directory of Laravel Project.**

**Where `D:\Laragon\www\krutech` is the Laravel Project**

**translate.js code:**

```
const { translate } = require('@vitalets/google-translate-api');

function translateText(text, targetLang) {
    return translate(text, { to: targetLang })
        .then(res => {
            return res.text;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            return "Translation failed";
        });
}

module.exports = {
    translateText: translateText
};

const textToTranslate = process.argv[2];
const targetLang = process.argv[3];

if (textToTranslate && targetLang) {
    translateText(textToTranslate, targetLang)
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch((err) => console.error(`Translation failed: ${err}`));
} else {
    console.error('Please provide text to translate and target language code');
}
```

**Laravel Controller Function code:**

```
public function index()
    {
        $text = 'I want to try convert my text into hindi language.';
        $targetLang = 'hi';

        $pathToTranslateJS = base_path('translate.js');
        $command = "node " . $pathToTranslateJS . " " . escapeshellarg($text) . " " . $targetLang;

        $process = new Process([$command]);
        $process->run();

        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
        }

        $translatedText = $process->getOutput();
        return  $translatedText;

    }
```

When I try to run node file from command line with this command it is working fine and I am getting my required result.

> CMD : `node translate.js "I want to try convert my text into hindi language." hi`
>
> Result : `मैं अपने टेक्स्ट को हिंदी भाषा में बदलने की कोशिश करना चाहता हूं।`

But What is the problem with Laravel controller? I am not able to find how to solve?

**My current Laravel version is 7.29**

Comment: you should try executing that command in the command line first to check if it is working in command line or not and then you can try executing it in laravel

Comment: @Shailendra Yes from cmd it is working. You can check inside question I have mentioned input output from cmd.

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/processes#invoking-processes

```php
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Process; 

    $result = Process::run('ls -la'); 
    $output = $result->output();
```

this is in the official documentation of the Process class

while you used

```php
$process = new Process([$command]);
$process->run();
```

Comment: Thanks for giving your effort but unfortunately in Laravel 7.* version there is no `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Process;`  class.

Answer (score -3):

From what I see in your error, code executes inside public folder, while you put js file in root directory, try moving it inside public or change code that it goes to root and then executes